# Effect of changing network name in NetworkManager

Tags: linux, networking, gnome, arch-linux

Today when I was changing some settings in NetworkManager (in Arch Linux with GNOME 3), I noticed there is this field "Name" under the "Identity" tab that I can change. It was set to "enp0s31f6" before (my MAC address is "xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx (enp0s31f6)"), and I changed it to "eth0" to see what would happen. Well, actually nothing seemed to have changed -- The output of `ip link show` doesn't contain "eth0" at all, only "enp0s31f6".

The only place where I could find anything about "eth0" is in the file `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/eth0`:

```
[connection]
id=eth0
uuid=a31aa62a-99d1-4db0-8140-08579b064005
type=ethernet
interface-name=enp0s31f6
permissions=
secondaries=
timestamp=1481431757

...
```

So my question is, what effect does changing network device name has? Is it reflected anywhere else than in NetworkManager?